# How do I send multiple ports data as single string into flatfile informatica?

Tags: sql, etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-cloud

I have multiple variable ports which gave some fixed values assigned. I need to pass this variable ports into single output port as string and capture in flatfile.

Expression:

```
Id_v:'xxxx'
Password_v:'vbbccvn'
Key_v:'ryccdfj'
Outputport:
```

Required output in flat file:

```
Id:xxxxx
Password:vbbccvn
Key:ryccdfj
```

I have written the expression editor as follows
[image: expression editor image]

The mapping is as follows:
[image: mapping image]

the http is configured as follows, I need to get access token by  sending the first http request. Is the simple post right method as I'm sending as single body?
[image: HTTP transfrmatn image]

I'm getting error as repository error_12400[attributes, base url not found]
EP_12400 Repository error(Attribute name, base URL , cannot be found)
PCHTTP_33022:Cannot send transport parameter to Java
PCHTTP_33006:Error in getting URL for the connection(http_transformation)

Comment: can you pls use a variable port to calculate/concatenate whatever you want name it as v_temp_port , then use a out port to key = v_temp_port?

Comment: {
grant_type:password
client_id:xxxxxxxx
client_secret:yyyy
username:vvvvvv
password:nmnmnmn
}
above is output port sending this string for input HTTP transfmtn. Using GET and provided base URL, there is nothing in other fields(header,http-name, default value all blank) getting error:
REP_12400 Repository error(Attribute name, base URL , cannot be found)PCHTTP_33022:Cannot send transport parameter to Java
PCHTTP_33006:Error in getting URL for the connection(http_transformation)

Comment: not sure if they are related to variable port. can you pls post pic of mapping and the error msg in the question

Comment: added mapping , expression and http configurations along with error. In the Postman api they tested successful. Dont know if anything missing in the mapping or http transformation

Comment: I think you need add some certificates to informatica server. Certificates can be obtained from salesforce url. This seems to be a secured connection and you need to add those certificates to infa server.

Comment: Okay thank you. Is there any changes I need to make in napping expression or http transformation since it's similar to your scenario except we sending client I'd and client secret extra . Never worked with this http or webservices before

Comment: Was able to post request and get access token . I used post and sent individual ports. I have not used content type in http name or 'application/json'.Thank you for replying all my questions. Now working on to send access token and two fields to send second http request to post data

Comment: Do you any idea of encrypting files since I want to use parameter file to store credentials and secret key. I do not want to expose this in mapping level.

Comment: going to be very difficult. So, you can create a secured folder that only informatica admin can access.

Comment: Okay . I'm sending token in header and individual ports to http. It gives me response invalid session I'd or session expired. I mentioned header as bearer.

Comment: I think you need more help, could you pls connect to infa support?

Comment: First of all do you have idea that informatica power centre can be able send bearer token to rest api. Were you successfull in sending in your scenario. I, using informatica 10.5

Comment: yes, i did it in infa 10.2. But as i said, i needed, certificates from API server(for you its salesforce) so that infa can connect to SF. Now, do you have any other mapping like this? If yes, you can check out their configurations. if not, then i think, you need to ensure infa server can reach api server(SF) by adding certificates.  there can be many reasons of failure. here is a link that has more details. can you pls chk https://mastechinfotrellis.com/blog/use-informatica-power-center-restful-web-service-client

Comment: I have posted this in informatica network and i see there we cannot send bearer tokem authentication using http transformation and a feature request was raised to add this which is in progress still.refer below link
https://network.informatica.com/ideas/51664
still wonder how you were able to do, are you using powercentre or cloud

Comment: powercenter. is your informatica server on windows or linux? can you test api using informatica user ? use curl to test out your API using exact arguments and URL. if CURL works then i dont see any reason of failure of http.

Comment: its on unix .since it shows invalid session id it something with token. im sending bearer[space]token, i have added a port "Authorization" under header and connected this. input port im sending like {"id":cccccc" "email":ccc@.com"}. when i use default:'application/json' .. httpname: Content-Type.. method:simplepost. even if used default :application/xxx-www.urlencoded, it gives error response. just posting all in case i missed out any configuration. i am using the end url not the url returned by the oauth with token along with url

Comment: not 100% sure whats going on. did you test in UNIX using CURL?

Comment: i will try meanwhile if you dont mind. can you help to post image of the http tab of your mapping. i have only one header- "Authorization" to which i am sending Bearer token. is it we need to add another header ContentType with default-application/json.

Comment: curl - X POST -H "Authorization: Bearer token " -H "accept: application/json"  "endurl"

I am using above command not getting any output. can u check with the command.